# How can I keep players from taking the armor from armor stands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a server, and there is a bunch of armor stand statues, but all the players will break them. How do I stop them from taking the armor?

Comment: Do the armour stands need to be visible or are they just there for commands? If it's the latter, encasing them in bedrock would work.

Comment: They are for display. I thought about encasing them in barriers, but it would be way to blocky for what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop players breaking them, make the ArmorStand invulnerable:

```
/entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,r=5] {Invulnerable:1b}
```

To prevent players from taking the items on the ArmorStand, use the DisabledSlots tag:

```
/entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,r=5] {DisabledSlots:2039583}
```

Comment: Does it matter whats in the DisabledSlots tag?

Comment: @Kylun11 Yes, it states what sort of interactions are possible with each equipment slot. The wiki has a list of input values to use [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Armor_Stand/ED), but note that 1.9 has changed what these values do.

Answer (score 1):

The `/entitydata` command was removed in version `1.13` in favour of the newer `/data` command, so here's an updated version of the previous answer.

To make armour stands invulnerable use:

```
/data modify entity @e[limit=1,type=minecraft:armor_stand] Invulnerable set value true
```

To prevent players from taking items from an armour stand use:

```
/data modify entity @e[limit=1,type=minecraft:armor_stand] DisabledSlots set value 4144959
```

To summon an armour stand with these values already set at the user's current position, use:

```
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ { Invulnerable: true, DisabledSlots: 4144959 }
```

(Tested and confirmed to work in version `1.17.1`.)

---

The `DisabledSlots` value is derived from a [bitwise or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation?useskin=vector#OR) of the following values:

|  | Sword | Feet | Legs | Chest | Head | Shield | Unused | Unused |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Remove | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 32 | 64 | 128 |
| Replace | 256 | 512 | 1024 | 2048 | 4096 | 8192 | 16384 | 32768 |
| Apply | 65536 | 131072 | 262144 | 524288 | 1048576 | 2097152 | 4194304 | 8388608 |

Where:

- The *remove* flags prevent a piece of armour from being removed from an armour stand.
- The *replace* flags prevent a piece of armour on an armour stand from being replaced with new armour.
- The *apply* flags prevent a pice of armour from being added to an armour stand.

Hence a value of `4144959` prevents the removal, replacing, or application of all extant pieces of armour.

A value of `2039583` as given in the previous answer would block everything *except* shields, which were added more recently.

A value of `16777215` would block all currently existing pieces of armour, as well as making use of presently unallocated bits in an attempt to future-proof.